# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type ... to non-throwing function type

Tags: ios, swift3

This code continues to give me an error handling message near the URLSession instantiation. I am confused with swift3 help please.

```
 let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://myURL.com/user")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)&username=\(userUsername)"
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
            {

                (data: Data!, response: URLResponse!, error: Error!) in

                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                var err: NSError?
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                    if let parseJSON = json {
                        var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String;
                        print("result: \(resultValue)");
```

The error I get is:

> invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws ->()' to non-throwing function type

Comment: What's the exact error? Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: And why are you using all of those `NS` classes? Use `URL`, not `NSURL`. Use a Swift Dictionary, not `NSDictionary`, etc.

Comment: let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
        {

Comment: Again, what is the error message? Please don't make this difficult. If you want help you need to make it easy to help you.

Comment: invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws ->()' to non-throwing function type

Comment: It's actually on the opening curly brace of the function

Comment: Did you try to print the NSDictionary `json`?

Comment: No, all I tried to do, the only thing i tried to print was the error in the original code. 
invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws ->()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?)->Void'

Comment: Two issues: you're using `try` without a proper Do-Catch block, and you're using it inside the dataTask closure which won't work anyway. Use a callback to get the data out of the closure *then* deserialize JSON.

Comment: ^^ Thank you @EricAya, I found it out last night. But yes that was the problem

Comment: @DevelopingProgrammer You're welcome. Don't hesitate to write your own answer with code and explanations about what you've done to fix your issue if you think it could be useful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error means the following.

By default the function can throw, which is why it uses optionals for return values. Whenever the function throws, the optional values will be nil. However you remove the optional nil values using the exclamation mark operator.

You should read up on how to properly handle exceptions in Swift. Then you should be able to clean up your code and make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading. Just omit the type annotations, they do more harm than good.

And use the native structs without the `NS` prefix:

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://myURL.com/user")!
var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)&username=\(userUsername)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in ...
```